# How do you get a Umbreon or Epseon during reduced buddy distance?

Tags: pokemon-go

It is known that if you set an Eevee as your buddy for 10km (2 candies), then evolve it, it will turn into an Epseon or Umbreon depending on the time of day.

Now, there is a reduced buddy distance bonus from the Pokemon GO FEST. Eevee now requires walking 1.7km for a candy. So, is it still required to walk the 10km or just two candies worth distance (3.4km)?

For people who are wondering why I am not testing it myself, I am collecting Chansey Candy (a valuable process in a time which I must take advantage of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not attempted this trick, but according to [Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/evolve-umbreon-espeon-using-night-day-pokemon-go/), the buddy trick for Eevee requires both walking 10km and 2 candies.

> The Eevee must have 10 KMs walked **and** 2 Candy collected as your Buddy

When the km requirement for a buddy at the regular distance, the 10km and 2 candies will conveniently occur at the same time. During events where the amount of km is reduced, you are still required to accrue 10kms with Eevee